# My Matlab FIFO Buffer dequeue method is not working ("too many output arguments")

Tags: matlab, fifo

```
classdef fifoBufferNeu < handle
    properties
        fifoBuffer
        buffSize
    end
    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = fifoBufferNeu()
            obj.buffSize = 0;
            obj.fifoBuffer = [];
        end
        function obj = enqueue(obj, nElementIn)
            obj.fifoBuffer = nElementIn;
        end
        function obj = dequeue(obj)
            obj.fifoBuffer = nElementOut;
        end
    end
end
```

-> Command Window: `fifoBufferNeu().enqueue(8)` then `nElementOut = fifoBufferNeu().dequeue()`

Answer (score 1):

```
classdef fifoBufferNeu < handle
    properties
        fifoBuffer
        buffSize
    end
    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = fifoBufferNeu()
            obj.buffSize = 0;
            obj.fifoBuffer = [];
        end
        function enqueue(obj, nElementIn)
            obj.fifoBuffer = [obj.fifoBuffer; nElementIn];
            obj.buffSize = numel(obj.fifoBuffer);
        end
        function result = dequeue(obj)
            result = obj.fifoBuffer(1);
            obj.fifoBuffer = obj.fifoBuffer(2:end);
            obj.buffSize = numel(obj.fifoBuffer);
        end
    end
end
```

To use `fifo = fifoBufferNeu()` then `fifo.enqueue(8)` and `fifo.dequeue()`

- for a handle type object you don't need to return the object from the method.
- You DO need to create a single instance of the fifo to queue to and dequeue from. You were creating a new instance each time.
- You do need to actually add a value to a queue and return a value from a queue.

Comment: Thanks so much my friend!